# Reach Understanding Higher Order Component syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I am trying to understand the basic syntax of a React HOC. Consider below example;

```
//WithLoading.js
import React from 'react';
function WithLoading(Component) {
  return function WithLoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
    if (!isLoading) return <Component {...props} />;
    return <p>Hold on, fetching data might take some time.</p>;
  };
}
export default WithLoading;
```

And it is invoked/used as below;

```
const ListWithLoading = WithLoading(List);

render() {
return (
  <ListWithLoading
    isLoading={this.state.loading}
    repos={this.state.repos}
  />
);
```

}

Now my specific question is -
When we invoke the function WithLoading(), it actually returning an inner function (WithLoadingComponent). So if the returned thing i.e. ListWithLoading is a function and not a component, how are we able to use it as a component i.e.

```
<ListWithLoading
        isLoading={this.state.loading}
        repos={this.state.repos}
      />
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html, `ListWithLoading` seems to be a "function component"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to define a component is to write a JavaScript function:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element. We call such components “function components” because they are literally JavaScript functions.

And this is how we use it:

```
<Welcome name="Sara" />;
```

Isn't that the same ?) As long as your inner function returns "valid React stuff" it is a valid “function component”.

```
// ListWithLoading is just a reference, 
// to a function [function WithLoadingComponent(...) {}] which 
// is valid react component (same like function Welcome(...) {}),
// that is why you can use it like <ListWithLoading />
const ListWithLoading = WithLoading(List);
```

Comment: Oh k...Cool...and assume we can also use HOC as class component and similar analogy can be applied for that ?

Comment: Also not sure what you mean exactly by "valid React stuff"...All I can see is a JS function returning some amount of JSX code...That is all ?

Comment: @testndtv "valid React stuff" basically means react element. e.g `const element = <div />;` . And  this one  `const element = <Welcome />;`  - we can also call React element, the difference is that  this element represents user-defined component. We can have more complex stuff like `<div><Welcome name="A"/><Welcome name="B"/></div>` what is also a valid React stuff.

Comment: @testndtv and I used functional component just because it's very simple, it's gonna be the same for class components. When you see this `<Welcome name="aaa" />` you might not even care whether Welcome is a class or function component.  It will display greeting message somewhere anyway.

Comment: Ok Cool...got it...and just as a followup question on HOCs....are there broadly 2 types of HOCs - 1. Takes component and returns enhanced component directly
2. Takes component and returns a function (which then returns enhanced component)

I assume connect falls in 2nd category...Would you want to add anything on that ?

Comment: @testndtv If you're talking about reacr-redux `connect` than I don't want to guess here :) I haven't seen what it actually does under the hood and why it was done in that way. Higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component and whatever you need to do "in between" is up to you, you are not limited here.

Comment: @testndtv react-redux `connect` is not the HOC itself because it does not take a component, but rather some "helpers" it needs to be able to decorate a component with later and returns HOC which then takes a component a returns an enhanced one.